# Set ImageView auto height depends on the image width

Tags: android, imageview, universal-image-loader

Is There a way to set an auto height on an ImageView depends on the width? For example in Javascript, if you set width on an image, it calculate the image's height auto

My app loads image from the server, depends on the user's preferences. It can be an 200dp x 50dp size or 50dp x 50dp

I'm using Android Image Loader. If I set on the ImageView `wrap_content` for width and height, it shows nothing

This is my UIL default config:

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisk(true).cacheInMemory(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .build();

ImageLoaderConfiguration defaultConfiguration =
            new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
                    .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                    .diskCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024)
                    .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                    .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
                    .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
                    .build();

ImageLoader.getInstance().init(defaultConfiguration);
```

And for the image:

```
new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_user_default)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_user_default)
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_user_default)
            .build();
```

I tried using `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`, `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` and `android:scaleType="fitXY"` but nothing works

------- EDITED ------------

I ended doing by myself, this maybe help other:

```
  imageLoader.displayImage(logoUrl, logoPhoto, options2, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                // Max dimension for logo images
                int maxWidth = 879, maxHeight = 400;
                // Get the correct dp scale measure
                final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                // Width of the image donwloaded
                int width = loadedImage.getWidth();
                // Height of the image donwloaded
                int height = loadedImage.getHeight();
                // Convert image width px on dp
                int widthInDp = (int) (width * scale);
                // Convert image height px on dp
                int heightInDp = (int) (height * scale);

                Log.d(TAG, String.format("Original image size: %s, %s", width, height));
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("Original image size in DP: %s, %s", widthInDp, heightInDp));
                if (heightInDp > maxHeight) {
                    double reductionPercentage = ((maxHeight * 100) / heightInDp);

                    widthInDp = (int) (widthInDp * (reductionPercentage / 100));
                    heightInDp = (int) (heightInDp * (reductionPercentage / 100));

                    Log.d(TAG, String.format("Height | Recalculating height and width: %s, %s", widthInDp, heightInDp));

                }

                if (widthInDp > maxWidth) {
                    double reductionPercentage = ((maxWidth * 100) / widthInDp);

                    widthInDp = (int) (widthInDp * (reductionPercentage / 100));
                    heightInDp = (int) (heightInDp * (reductionPercentage / 100));

                    Log.d(TAG, String.format("Width | Recalculating height and width: %s, %s", widthInDp, heightInDp));
                }

                logoPhoto.getLayoutParams().width = widthInDp;
                logoPhoto.getLayoutParams().height = heightInDp;
            }
        });
```

Thanks to Muhammad Hamza Shahid for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the Complete section of Readme of the library [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) there is a code snipet

```
ImageSize targetSize = new ImageSize(80, 50); // result Bitmap will be fit   to this size
imageLoader.loadImage(imageUri, targetSize, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
@Override
public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
    // Do whatever you want with Bitmap
}
});
```

this will load image, decode it to Bitmap and return Bitmap to callback
and here you can set height width using targetSize

Comment: I tried it, but same results. Image doesn't show if i use wrap content in any of them

Comment: @LTroya use this https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader it has image sizing options

Comment: I am already using it. I was debugging the size of the image that the library donwload and it was fine. I figure out that the problems is after it download the image. I am looking for a way to resize the image in equals width and height and set it to the imageView programmatically

Comment: Thanks, it helps me. I use it to calculate the size from the image the library donwloaded